# Get value from session and display in an item (date picker) in Oracle APEX

Tags: datepicker, oracle-apex

Refer to Figure 1, after user selected `Start Date` and `End Date`, then click on the `Search` button. When the `Search` button is clicked, the action submit page will be performed. But after the page is refresh, the value in the date picker is empty and the value is stored in the session.

My questions are:

1. How to get a value from session and display on an item
2. How to keep the value of dates in date pickers.

[image: Figure 1: Date Picket]
[image: Figure 1: Session]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, value in the item have to be saved after submit. If your item loses its value after button click, then you have made something to that. There is a number of ways to do it, sometimes not obvious, so first check:

1. Item's properties, `Source` tab
2. Processes on the page - it could be a process with type `Clear Session State`

After that, try to remember all what you did after creating items. Create new page from scratch, add desired items and button with default properties, then make changes in properties one by one and check every change.

Answer (score 0):

In the branch for that submit action, make sure you have entered "set items". Set the  item "P20_START_DATE" with the value "&P20_START_DATE'".
In Apex 5, go to the branch, click on "Target" in the behaviour session and set the values there.

Answer (score 0):

Summary, the way to maintain a value in an item after page submit is

1. Click on the item
2. Navigate to `Source` tab
3. Set `Type` to item
4. Set the `Item` to the Item you want to keep the value